# Problem importing ZEXP files programmatically

Tags: import, menu, plone

I'm developing a Plone Product that needs to import objects programmatically previously exported to ZEXP files. It's working perfectly, except the navigation bar. When one object is imported, it does so correctly, but the navication bar is not updated. The object can be accessed through it's URL and it's parent container contents tab.

Bellow is the code I used to import the objects. It's based on zope's ObjectManager._importObjectFromFile implementation.

```
def importDocument( app, fileName, container ):
    app._p_jar.sync()   

    owner = 1

    connection = container._p_jar
    ob = connection.importFile( config.REMOTE_DIR + fileName, customImporters={ magic: importXML, } )

    id = ob.id
    if hasattr(id, 'im_func'): id = id()

    try:
        container._setObject( id, ob, set_owner = owner, suppress_events=False )
    except AttributeError:
        print "AttributeError"

    # Try to make ownership implicit if possible in the context
    # that the object was imported into
    ob = container._getOb( id )
    ob.manage_changeOwnershipType( explicit = 0 )

    transaction.commit()

    return True
```

I've noticed that the _setObject implementation fires an ObjectAddedEvent event in it's code, and it's after that event that the menu gets updated when I use the ZMI interface to import an object, so I figure something is listening to this event and handling the menu, but oddly, it doesn't happen when using my code.

Comment: Have you tried to obj.reindexObject() after import?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, importing zexp objects is not supported (in part due to cases like this where  unexpected or unintended results may occur). If it works, great. If it doesn't, you are "on your own" and probably better off copying the Data.fs file to a new software stack.

That said, I'm not sure I understand why clear and rebuild the catalog (ZMI -> portal_catalog -> tab 'advance' -> 'clear & rebuild') is not the answer here. According to its description its job is to "walk the entire portal looking for content objects which should be indexed in the catalog and index them".

Unless I misunderstand, you've just described a situation where newly imported content "should be indexed" because it hasn't been indexed yet.

If you are worried about the length of time required to clear and rebuild, try running it from the command line with something like this:

- http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.org/Products.PloneOrg/trunk/scripts/catalog_rebuild.py

If you are worried about crawling the whole site, then call indexObject() on each object (http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/plone.org/Products.PloneOrg/trunk/scripts/catalog_rebuild.py#L109)

Comment: Hey aclark, thanks for the suggestion. But... sure, it's a situation where the newly imported object needs to be indexed, but not the whole catalog. Erasing the catalog and reindexing all objects every time a new object is imported seems a little extreme and ilogical, doesn't it? Considering this is gonna happen in a live server, I don't think it's a good solution. We are talking about thousands of documents here, edited/created (and thus imported in that live instance) by multiple users.

Comment: No, it doesn't sound extreme and illogical to me, assuming you want to fix the problem :-). The catalog_rebuild.py is designed specifically to be run on a production server (plone.org in this case). In any event, at the very least you'll need to get a list of those objects (if you refuse to clear & rebuild via catalog_rebuild.py) and call indexObject() on them. I have updated my answer with a link to where catalog_rebuild.py calls indexObject().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try manually rebuilding the whole catalog after the import is complete? It might give you more hints to what is wrong ...

ZMI -> portal_catalog -> tab 'advance' -> 'clear & rebuild'.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may need to "publish" the object after import to make it visible.
2. Use the manage_importObject method instead.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of just making it visible. Even if it's not published, I should be able to see it in a private state when logged with a manager account.

Comment: I have seen that sometimes objects are visible in the ZMI but not in plone. Even for administrator. Are you able to see the object in the ZMI? See my other answer.